# SSIS Copy files task does not copy custom date column

Tags: ssis, filesystems, task

Well, I am facing one weird issue with Copy Files task i SSIS.

I have folder A in which I have sub folders and I am using Copy files task to copy all the Excel files in sub-folders to the folder A. I noticed that with some of the excel files where I have custom date column which is restricted by list to select dates from as I don't want user to input wrong date/format.

When I run the package the excel file is copied but that date column is not getting populated.

I am not getting the reason why its happening.

Can some one help? What approach I should follow to resolve it?

Comment: is that 'DATE' refencing to any external file?

Comment: @LONG no it’s not referencing any external data source. I have another sheet where I have listed all the values for the filter.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I did is in place of Copy file from the drop down of the component I selected move file and ran it once. And then again I ran with Copy command and it some how worked. I am not happy this though. I have put in a solution at the end of SSIS package where after the files are loaded to SQL table I am deleting them from the source folder using looping component.

For now it seem to be working. but exact reason for not copying the particular custom date field is still a question.

[image]